# How do I do a bit-wise XOR on NSData in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, nsdata, endianness, xor

I have two NSData objects, data1 and data2, and I'd like to do a bit-wise XOR and store the result in a third NSData object, xorData.

The first thing I tried was this:

```
*data1.bytes^*data2.bytes;
```

but it gave an error of:

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('const void' and 'const void')

So I tried to write a function that would extract the bytes of the data into an array of integers, perform the xor on the integers, then save the result back into an NSData object. The function looks like this:

```
+(NSData *) DataXOR1:(NSData *) data1
DataXOR2:(NSData *)data2{
    const int *data1Bytes = [data1 bytes];
    const int *data2Bytes = [data2 bytes];
    NSMutableArray *xorBytes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
    for (int i = 0; i < data1.length;i++){
         [xorBytes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(data1Bytes[i]^data2Bytes[i])]];
    }
    NSData *xorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:xorBytes];
    return xorData;
}
```

This runs, but gives the wrong answers. When I test it on two simple pieces of data (data1 = 0x7038 and data2 = 0x0038), and use NSLog to output what the values are, I get:

```
data1Bytes[0] = 8070450532247943280
data2Bytes[0] = 8070450532247943168
data1Bytes[0]^data2Bytes[0] = 112
data1Bytes[1] = 10376302331560798334
data2Bytes[1] = 10376302331560798334
data1Bytes[1]^data2Bytes[1] = 0
```

This boggles my mind a bit because the values in the dataXBytes arrays are totally wrong, but they're xor-ing to the right values! (0x70 ^ 0x00 = 0x70 = 112)

I think it might be an endian-ness problem, but when I change the initialization of data1Bytes to:

```
const int *data1Bytes = CFSwapInt32BigToHost([data1 bytes]);
```

it runs into an error when it tries to access it, saying:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address = 0xa08ad539)

Is there a much simpler way to do the xor? If not, how can I fix the endian problem?

Comment: If you get arrays of bytes out of the NSData objects, why do you declare them to be `int` arrays???  (And that's just one of your problems.)

Comment: FYI, `8070450532247943280` = `0x7000000000003870`. And `8070450532247943168` = `0x7000000000003800`. So the xor looks fine to me. The problem, as Hot Licks suggests, that you're using `int *` pointers and getting 64 bit numbers. What is the underlying data? Is there a reason you're not using something more representative of a byte (e.g. `uint8_t`)? What precisely are you trying to do? You don't show us what is in the `NSData` objects, so it's hard for us to offer counsel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting to `int` then archiving an `NSArray` of `NSNumber`s will definitely not create the result you're looking for. You'll want to have some mutable `NSData` to which you append the individual bytes to, something like

```
+(NSData *) DataXOR1:(NSData *) data1
            DataXOR2:(NSData *)data2{
    const char *data1Bytes = [data1 bytes];
    const char *data2Bytes = [data2 bytes];
    // Mutable data that individual xor'd bytes will be added to
    NSMutableData *xorData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++){
        const char xorByte = data1Bytes[i] ^ data2Bytes[i];
        [xorData appendBytes:&xorByte length:1];
    }
    return xorData;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly!


If you don't mind answering two questions about this, though:

1) Why is char the best choice for pointing to a generic byte of data?

2) As I understand it, the loop initializes the variable "xorByte" in every iteration so that it will allocate a spot in memory for the data, then "appendBytes:&xorByte" causes xorData to point to all of these new variables. Is that right?

Comment: (1) `char` is guaranteed to actually be a single byte, whereas `int` is not. (2) `xorByte` is a stack variable that goes in and out of stack memory on every loop (though there may be an optimization that makes it more long-lived), the call to `-appendBytes:length:` actually *copies* the value of `xorByte` into `xorData`'s internal data.

Answer (score 1):

```
+ (NSData *) xorData:(NSData *)data1 with:(NSData *)data2
{
    // make data1 smaller
    if (data1.length > data2.length) {
        NSData *t = data1;
        data1 = data2;
        data2 = t;
    }

    char *xor = (char *) malloc(data2.length * sizeof(char));
    char * data1Bytes = (char *) data1.bytes;
    char * data2Bytes = (char *) data2.bytes;

    for (int i = 0; i <data1.length; i++)
    {
        xor[i] = data1Bytes[i] ^ data2Bytes[i];
    }

    NSMutableData *data = [[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithBytes:xor length:data1.length] autorelease];
    [data appendData:[data2 subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(data1.length, data2.length - data1.length)]];
    free(xor);
    return [NSData dataWithData:data];
}
```

Comment: 1. Don't cast the result of `malloc`. 2. Why malloc in the first place? Use the `NSMutableData` instead and avoid the copy. 3. Don't perform another needless copy (in the last line).

Comment: I would like to return NSData, not NSMutableData, then whats the best way?

Comment: What's the point in returning a (non mutable) `NSData`? The instance is created in your local source code and not shared or stored. It can't be mutated after the method returns. The caller can't tell the difference between the mutable instance and the non-mutable copy.

Comment: Just best practice. "It can't be mutated after the method returns." > are you sure about that. I don't think so. If cast to a NSMutableData, the return value can be mutated since the original pointer is a mutable object.

Comment: That's right, the caller *could* do that. But that would be the caller's (bad) decision. The caller should, of course, not do this, as it means relying on an implementation detail of the xor method. It should not be the xor method's concern that outside code might abuse its return value.